# if div has class change content - three cases

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three possible cases for a div - it either has a class .first or .last or none.

I need to change the content another div based on these classes, but I'm doing something wrong...

Can someone give me hand and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()  {

    if (jQuery('.pricing-plan').hasClass('first')) {
        jQuery('.tagline').text('primeiro');
    }
    else if (jQuery('.pricing-plan').hasClass('last')) {
        jQuery('.tagline').text('ultimo');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.tagline').text('nada');
    }

});
```

Comment: Post a fiddle or your HTML structure

Comment: I don't see any error in posted jQuery code.

Comment: You're doing everything right

Comment: The only case this would not work: if you assigned the class dynamically, _after_ `DOMContentLoaded` already has been fired.

Comment: check your jquery library path

Comment: what went wrong ? What do you need from your script ?

Comment: @rplantiko Ha ha. WHat? Are you serious? "jQuery(document).ready(function ()..:"

Comment: The only case this would not work is you have multiple elements with the same class

Comment: @shaunakde That doesn't make sense?

Comment: @JoakimM If there are multiple elements with same class, the `if()` condition would only accept first element.

Comment: @JoakimM Of course. But DOM could be manipulated after this script has already been executed. @shaunakde - oh yes, he could have several `.pricing-plan` elements, some of them with, others without class `.first` / `.last`

Comment: @rplantiko, seems OP has vanished/not interested.

Comment: SorrY, I was creating the js fiddle.

Here it goes http://jsfiddle.net/licinio/4vgXS/

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vgXS/1/)**

- You have multiple elements with class `.pricing-plan` and `.tagline`. In such cases you have to use `.each()` to iterate over each element.
- Inside each, to get context of current `.pricing-plan` use `$(this)`
- In your current code the selector `jQuery('.pricing-plan')` just
  returned/checked first `.pricing-plan`

---

Check this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.pricing-plan').each(function () {

        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('first')) {
            jQuery(this).find('.tagline').text('primeiro');
        } else if (jQuery(this).hasClass('last')) {
            jQuery(this).find('.tagline').text('ultimo');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).find('.tagline').text('nada');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: PERFECT!! THANK YOU!!

Can you tell me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Added the points in the answer, you had multiple classes with same name.